# Does oracle create partition at the level of a data block

Tags: oracle11g

When we create a partition in an oracle database table, does the partition get created at the level of a data block/data file which is the most fundamental level?

Or is it created at a higher level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A non-partitioned table is a collection of metadata about columns (etc) and a data segment that is made of one or more extents of data blocks. Each extent can be on multiple data files, but only in a single tablespace.

In a partitioned table, each partition (or subpartition) is itself a data segment. This is why it is possible to perform a partition exchange between a single partition and a non-partitioned table (or between a subpartitioned partition and a partitioned table) -- the element that is exchanged is the data segment (or data segments).

In terms of storage structures alone, a single partition of a partitioned table is equivalent to a non-partitioned table.

Answer (score 1):

In it's simplest form - partition becomes a new segment (part of some tablespace)